# Ant replace in maven2?

Tags: configuration, maven-2, ant, build-process

I'm looking for some way to replace patterns in files with values, during build time.

E.g. a configuration file may look the same except that different machines requires different hostnames in some setting. In that case i want to have a template file, where hostname is replaced with @@hostname@@ 
Then when building, I want to create separate  versions of the file with the patter replaced with the correct value for each environment.

In ant you could use "replace", is there something similar in maven2? I know that I can run ant form maven, but if theres a maven plugin doing it, I'd prefer that one.

I found http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/ 
but it's very new...

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resource plugin is what does filtering in Maven. IIRC it supports the ant syntax as well as the ${foo} maven syntax.

Answer (score 3):

keep up with the [maven-replacer-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/), the project is still alive and well

Answer (score 2):

Maven's [resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [Maven-ant](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) plug-in?

Comment: I would like to stick to maven if possible

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using the maven-antrun-plugin to help out with a maven build.  That's fine.  In this case, though I think the resources plugin is probably a better match, as Steve said.